# Filter only by top-level items in QSortFilterProxyModel

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtreeview, qsortfilterproxymodel

I use a `QTreeView` (PyQt 5) to display available fonts, which works quite well. In addition I have a `QLineEdit` to set the filter expression using `QSortFilterProxyModel.setFilterRegExp()`, which *seems* to work well too.

The problem is that I want the filter to only apply to the top-level entries. My tree is displayed like so:

```
> Helvetica LT Std
  > Helvetica LT Std
      Italic
      Bold
      Regular
  > Helvetica LT Std Black
      Regular
      Italic
```

etc. This means when  I enter "Helv" as the regular expression all other fonts are correctly hidden, but also the style lines because they don't have the font name in them.

From what I understand I should subclass `QSortFilterProxyModel` and override the `filterAcceptsRow()` method. In that I would call `super()` to apply the regular filtering if the row is a top-level entry, otherwise return `True` to avoid filtering the child elements.

My problem is how to determine if the row has a parent other than the model's `invisibleRootItem()`. Probably it's super easy but I'm still confused about the architecture.

I have the interface for the overriding function:

```
def filterAcceptsRow(self, row, parent):
```

In that `row` is just an integer and I can't do anything with it (?) and `parent` is a `QModelIndex`, which is a non-persistent reference, right? The question to be answered is "does this index point to the `invisibleRootItem()` of the source model?".

How can I ask about that condition?

Comment: A hint: if `parent` is null - it refers to the top level items, otherwise it points to the parent item.

Comment: OK, it wasn't completely accurate but brought me on the right track (see my answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the [hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51420099/filter-only-by-top-level-items-in-qsortfilterproxymodel#comment89811124_51420099) in @vahancho's comment I can answer this question myself.

The `parent` argument already "knows" the answer. In PyQt (at least) `parent` will not be "null" (or `None`) if the parent is the invisible root. It is still a `QModelIndex` object but its `isValid()` method will return `False`.

So my subclass looks like:

```
class FontFilterProxyModel(QSortFilterProxyModel):
    """Custom proxy model that ignores child elements in filtering"""

    def filterAcceptsRow(self, row, parent):
        if parent.isValid():
            # Do not apply the filter to child elements
            return True
        else:
            return super(FontFilterProxyModel, self).filterAcceptsRow(row, parent)
```